# When cleaning view cache in Laravel, browser still shows cached files

Tags: php, laravel, caching, browser-cache

After removing /storage/framework/view files, I still see the cached version of views until I clean also browser cache. I know that it's possible to set 'Cache-control' header, but is there more elegant way to automatically tell browsers that the view has been changed? The same way we do this with versioning of js/css files.

Comment: Since PHP is purely serverside and you have no control over the browser, I believe the header is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

with this route you can cleare all cache:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    echo '<h1>Cache facade value cleared</h1>';

    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    echo '<h1>Route cache cleared</h1>';

    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    echo '<h1>View cache cleared</h1>';

    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return '<h1>Clear Config cleared</h1>';
});
```

you can control cache in header for browser:

```
return view('some_template')->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0');
```

Comment: Would this actually work? Looks like it's just clearing the locally stored cache. You'll still have the problem with browsers

Comment: you can control cache in header for browser

Comment: Ok yes, you added that part to your answer after I already commented. OP has already stated in their question about the use of cache control

Answer (score 0):

You can not manipulate the client's browser with PHP. but there is a trick:

To get rid of css or js caching in the client's browser you can rename the js or css file. for example change `index.css` to `index1.css`. with the trick when the browser faces the `index1.css` can not find the file in the cash and reload it. :)